# Angular 2: ngOnInit is called AFTER trying to render template when start from url with id

Tags: typescript, angular

I'm working on an angular app that uses Router that links to multiple component from `AppComponent`. Here is a simplified version on [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/udbHDD2nTyUekliypACw?p=preview) to illustrate the issue (for some reason, the exact same code runs locally but not on plunker.)

When the app starts from `http://localhost:3000` or `http://localhost:3000/home`, the links `fruit1` and `fruit2` works fine (clicking leads to URL changing to `http://localhost:3000/fruit/1` with description text). However, the problem is that when starting on this url `http://localhost:3000/fruit/1` (typing in this url and hit enter), it seems that the call to service inside `fruit-detail.component.ts`'s `ngOnInit` is called AFTER trying to render its html component, which causes the stack trace below:

```
EXCEPTION: TypeError: Cannot read property 'description' of null in [ desc: {{fruit.description}}  in FruitDetailComponent@1:6]
angular2.dev.js:23925 EXCEPTION: TypeError: Cannot read property 'description' of null in [ desc: {{fruit.description}}  in FruitDetailComponent@1:6]BrowserDomAdapter.logError @ angular2.dev.js:23925BrowserDomAdapter.logGroup @ angular2.dev.js:23936ExceptionHandler.call @ angular2.dev.js:1320(anonymous function) @ angular2.dev.js:12857schedulerFn @ angular2.dev.js:13264SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub @ Rx.js:10775SafeSubscriber.next @ Rx.js:10730Subscriber._next @ Rx.js:10690Subscriber.next @ Rx.js:10667Subject._finalNext @ Rx.js:11191Subject._next @ Rx.js:11183Subject.next @ Rx.js:11142EventEmitter.emit @ angular2.dev.js:13245NgZone._zoneImpl.ng_zone_impl_1.NgZoneImpl.onError @ angular2.dev.js:13666NgZoneImpl.inner.inner.fork.onHandleError @ angular2.dev.js:2143ZoneDelegate.handleError @ angular2-polyfills.js:394Zone.runGuarded @ angular2-polyfills.js:300NgZoneImpl.runInner @ angular2.dev.js:2155NgZone.run @ angular2.dev.js:13749(anonymous function) @ angular2.dev.js:12956schedulerFn @ angular2.dev.js:13264SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub @ Rx.js:10775SafeSubscriber.next @ Rx.js:10730Subscriber._next @ Rx.js:10690Subscriber.next @ Rx.js:10667Subject._finalNext @ Rx.js:11191Subject._next @ Rx.js:11183Subject.next @ Rx.js:11142EventEmitter.emit @ angular2.dev.js:13245NgZone._checkStable @ angular2.dev.js:13689NgZone._zoneImpl.ng_zone_impl_1.NgZoneImpl.setMicrotask @ angular2.dev.js:13660NgZoneImpl.inner.inner.fork.onHasTask @ angular2.dev.js:2135ZoneDelegate.hasTask @ angular2-polyfills.js:449ZoneDelegate._updateTaskCount @ angular2-polyfills.js:466ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ angular2-polyfills.js:427Zone.runTask @ angular2-polyfills.js:320drainMicroTaskQueue @ angular2-polyfills.js:541ZoneTask.invoke @ angular2-polyfills.js:493
angular2.dev.js:23925 ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: TypeError: Cannot read property 'description' of nullBrowserDomAdapter.logError @ angular2.dev.js:23925ExceptionHandler.call @ angular2.dev.js:1329(anonymous function) @ angular2.dev.js:12857schedulerFn @ angular2.dev.js:13264SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub @ Rx.js:10775SafeSubscriber.next @ Rx.js:10730Subscriber._next @ Rx.js:10690Subscriber.next @ Rx.js:10667Subject._finalNext @ Rx.js:11191Subject._next @ Rx.js:11183Subject.next @ Rx.js:11142EventEmitter.emit @ angular2.dev.js:13245NgZone._zoneImpl.ng_zone_impl_1.NgZoneImpl.onError @ angular2.dev.js:13666NgZoneImpl.inner.inner.fork.onHandleError @ angular2.dev.js:2143ZoneDelegate.handleError @ angular2-polyfills.js:394Zone.runGuarded @ angular2-polyfills.js:300NgZoneImpl.runInner @ angular2.dev.js:2155NgZone.run @ angular2.dev.js:13749(anonymous function) @ angular2.dev.js:12956schedulerFn @ angular2.dev.js:13264SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub @ Rx.js:10775SafeSubscriber.next @ Rx.js:10730Subscriber._next @ Rx.js:10690Subscriber.next @ Rx.js:10667Subject._finalNext @ Rx.js:11191Subject._next @ Rx.js:11183Subject.next @ Rx.js:11142EventEmitter.emit @ angular2.dev.js:13245NgZone._checkStable @ angular2.dev.js:13689NgZone._zoneImpl.ng_zone_impl_1.NgZoneImpl.setMicrotask @ angular2.dev.js:13660NgZoneImpl.inner.inner.fork.onHasTask @ angular2.dev.js:2135ZoneDelegate.hasTask @ angular2-polyfills.js:449ZoneDelegate._updateTaskCount @ angular2-polyfills.js:466ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ angular2-polyfills.js:427Zone.runTask @ angular2-polyfills.js:320drainMicroTaskQueue @ angular2-polyfills.js:541ZoneTask.invoke @ angular2-polyfills.js:493
angular2.dev.js:23925 ORIGINAL STACKTRACE:BrowserDomAdapter.logError @ angular2.dev.js:23925ExceptionHandler.call @ angular2.dev.js:1332(anonymous function) @ angular2.dev.js:12857schedulerFn @ angular2.dev.js:13264SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub @ Rx.js:10775SafeSubscriber.next @ Rx.js:10730Subscriber._next @ Rx.js:10690Subscriber.next @ Rx.js:10667Subject._finalNext @ Rx.js:11191Subject._next @ Rx.js:11183Subject.next @ Rx.js:11142EventEmitter.emit @ angular2.dev.js:13245NgZone._zoneImpl.ng_zone_impl_1.NgZoneImpl.onError @ angular2.dev.js:13666NgZoneImpl.inner.inner.fork.onHandleError @ angular2.dev.js:2143ZoneDelegate.handleError @ angular2-polyfills.js:394Zone.runGuarded @ angular2-polyfills.js:300NgZoneImpl.runInner @ angular2.dev.js:2155NgZone.run @ angular2.dev.js:13749(anonymous function) @ angular2.dev.js:12956schedulerFn @ angular2.dev.js:13264SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub @ Rx.js:10775SafeSubscriber.next @ Rx.js:10730Subscriber._next @ Rx.js:10690Subscriber.next @ Rx.js:10667Subject._finalNext @ Rx.js:11191Subject._next @ Rx.js:11183Subject.next @ Rx.js:11142EventEmitter.emit @ angular2.dev.js:13245NgZone._checkStable @ angular2.dev.js:13689NgZone._zoneImpl.ng_zone_impl_1.NgZoneImpl.setMicrotask @ angular2.dev.js:13660NgZoneImpl.inner.inner.fork.onHasTask @ angular2.dev.js:2135ZoneDelegate.hasTask @ angular2-polyfills.js:449ZoneDelegate._updateTaskCount @ angular2-polyfills.js:466ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ angular2-polyfills.js:427Zone.runTask @ angular2-polyfills.js:320drainMicroTaskQueue @ angular2-polyfills.js:541ZoneTask.invoke @ angular2-polyfills.js:493
angular2.dev.js:23925 TypeError: Cannot read property 'description' of null
    at AbstractChangeDetector.ChangeDetector_FruitDetailComponent_0.detectChangesInRecordsInternal (viewFactory_FruitDetailComponent:30)
    at AbstractChangeDetector.detectChangesInRecords (angular2.dev.js:9689)
    at AbstractChangeDetector.runDetectChanges (angular2.dev.js:9672)
    at AbstractChangeDetector._detectChangesInViewChildren (angular2.dev.js:9751)
    at AbstractChangeDetector.runDetectChanges (angular2.dev.js:9676)
    at AbstractChangeDetector._detectChangesContentChildren (angular2.dev.js:9745)
    at AbstractChangeDetector.runDetectChanges (angular2.dev.js:9673)
    at AbstractChangeDetector._detectChangesInViewChildren (angular2.dev.js:9751)
    at AbstractChangeDetector.runDetectChanges (angular2.dev.js:9676)
    at AbstractChangeDetector.detectChanges (angular2.dev.js:9661)
```

And after that, this is logged to the console, which is why i suspect ngOnInit is called after. So how to have a working app when even loading directly from 'fruit/1' url? Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

```
===== extract data called!!
fruit-detail.component.ts:25 got fruit inside fruitComponent !apple
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the elvis operator for this:

```
<h2> desc: {{fruit?.description}} </h2>
```

In fact, the call `this._foodService.getData()` is executed asynchronously and you get the result after the `ngOnInit` method returns.

Since you use routing I think that the `OnActivate` interface and its `routerOnActivate` method is what you're looking for. If you return a promise within this method, the component will wait for the promise to be resolved before changing the route. So when the component will be displayed the data will be there and you don't have such problem.

Here is a sample:

```
@Component({
  (...)
})
export class FruitDetailComponent implements OnInit, OnActivate {
  fruit = null;

  constructor(
    private _rbacService: FoodService,
    private _routeParams: RouteParams) {}

  routerOnActivate(next: ComponentInstruction,
                   prev: ComponentInstruction) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      let id = +this._routeParams.get('id');
      console.log('on init fruit component: id = '+id);
      //get read write roles
      this._rbacService.getData().subscribe(data =>{
        this.fruit = data['fruits'].filter(obj => obj.id === id)[0];
        console.log('got fruit inside fruitComponent '+this.fruit.description);
        resolve(null);
      })
    });
  }
}
```

See this link for more details:

- https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/OnActivate-interface.html

Comment: thanks for the reply! it's interesting that using the 2nd option (`OnActivate`) didn't work; still got the same error. but the elvis operator does the trick! so, is it true that with elvis operator, the variables evaluated null at first get evaluated again later? is there a way to turn on the "Elvis mode" everywhere inside a template? it's a drag having to add '?' after every variable. thanks!

Comment: The fact that you can return a promise from the `onActivate` method is the super helpful part here.